# Lobster Google fonts doesn't works

Tags: css, fonts

I have some problems with Lobster font. When I open the site in Safari browser, some words loading correctly and others words doesn't works.
how you can see in the snap bellow:
[first image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pAgUY.png)

[second image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j9a8B.png)

Here are the code for both:

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lobster');
.second-image{
    font-size: 30px;
    color: #d91a56;
    font-family: 'Lobster',cursive;
    line-height: 30px;
    font-weight: 300;
    }
    .first-image{
    font-size: 30px;
    line-height: 30px;
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: 300;
    font-family: 'Lobster',cursive;
    }
```

Could help me?

Comment: Can we see the html that it is used in? It would help us determine the problem.

Comment: Yes the first image is: 
<h2><span>Índice</span></h2>
And the second one is:
<h3><span>Introdução</span></h3>

Comment: I mean post a minimal, relevant section of HTML code in your original question. Here is a link helping you how to do this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow by the way :)

Comment: I think Lobster not working might actually be a blessing.

Comment: I can't see what's wrong - the pictures you link to appear to represent the words in your HTML spans accurately? Am I missing something?

Comment: @moopet The letters "ç" and "ã", aren't corrects

Comment: Does Lobster contain those characters in the first place?

Comment: And is your HTML saved in the right encoding?  Does the file have a `http-equiv` in the header giving the charset?  Use utf8 if possible.

Comment: @Lorehead yes, i'm using utf-8

Comment: @Lorehead yes this contain because when I try in google chrome it works

Comment: The version on FontSquirrel does have those glyphs.  Probably the encoding. So try saving your file as UTF8 with a BOM; every browser that can use web fonts should support that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Lobster you load contains only the standard latin glyphs. You need `latin-ext` (latin extended) subset as well. Like this:

```
https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lobster&subset=latin,latin-ext
```

### UPDATE

You HTML contains glyphs existing of two parts. One is the `a` and the other is `combine tilde`. Together they make `ã`. Which is actually something different than `ã` (yes visually the same) but this second a tilde lives at one codepoint. Check this snippet in Safari:

http://jsfiddle.net/allcaps/dhs6bpfh/

When I copy the strings into Python I get:

```
`>>> u"Introdução"
u'Introduc\u0327a\u0303o'
`>>> u"Introdução"
u'Introdu\xe7\xe3o'
```

You use the `a` and the combine tilde: http://unicode-table.com/en/0303/
You should use: http://unicode-table.com/en/00E3/

Copy paste these `çã` into your html and you're fine.

Comment: This didn't change anything. Thank you!

Comment: here is the link http://blog.criobanco.com.br/smart-guia if you wanna try something.

Comment: The title at the bottom 'Introdução' looks correct. Do you have Lobster installed on your system? Maybe it takes precedence or something... :/

Comment: If you open https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lobster&subset=latin,latin-ext you can see it looks for a local Lobster first...

Comment: It doesn't works only in Safari, in other browsers works.Do you know any tags that I can put in my .css to work on safari, or some .js file that I can include?